# CodeEval Sequence Trasformation algorithm

Tags: algorithm

The challenge description:

There are two sequences. The first sequence consists of digits "0" and "1", the second one consists of letters "A" and "B". The challenge is to determine whether it's possible to transform a given binary sequence into a string sequence using the following rules: 
1. "0" can be transformed into non empty sequence of letters "A" ("A", "AA", "AAA" etc.) 
2. "1" can be transformed into non empty sequence of letters "A" ("A", "AA", "AAA" etc.) or to non empty sequence of letters "B" ("B", "BB", "BBB" etc) e.g.

And some input: 

`1010 AAAAABBBBAAAA - valid 
00 AAAAAA - valid 
01001110 AAAABAAABBBBBBAAAAAAA - valid
1100110 BBAABABBA - not valid`

I wonder how algorithm should look like?

P.S. Have no any clue

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please expand on your question to show what you have already tried. As it stands, the question does not address a specific, programming related, issue. If this is homework and youy are completely stuck on where to start, perhaps ask your tutor.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'd like to mention that this is not homework, just brain warm up. I tried some recursive solution but the main problem is that 1 could be transformed not only to 'B' but to 'A' as well as.

Comment: Please provide some part of the implementation you have done so far, it makes commenting and answering easier.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem finally after a few days of trying various solutions.
I will not provide you the answer but here is the approach.

Take this test case for example:

```
1010 AAAAABBBBAAAA
```

Notice that 1010 can be replaced by the regular expression

```
(A+|B+)A+(A+|B+)A+
```

This regular expression can generate an infinite number of strings, the worst case time complexity of doing  this analysis against a string is exponential

But the string "AAAAABBBBAAAA" can only be described by a finite amount of regular expressions composed of (A+)s and (A+|B+)s, or in this case, 0s and 1s

Answer (score 1):

You could try a recursive solution or dynamic programming. Note that each transformation

1. reduces the number of 1s or 0s by one,
2. cannot make the string shorter.

this means that in each recursive transformation, the number of As or Bs can be bounded in such a way that the length of the resulting string is no longer than the A-B-string in the input.

More strucurally, the problem can pe perhaps tackled with the [CYK-Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm).